# configuring attributes in MIM2016

Tags: identitymanager

In MIM2016 under Management Agents when creating a connector, is it possible to place logic in the attribute flow?   I'm importing a field, I want to change it to a specific value based on the value of another field that I am importing.

memberID
countrycode

If countrycode = A then memberID = 'countryname'

If this is possible, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

When you set up your attribute flow, you need to choose "Advanced" instead of "Direct" regarding the Mapping Type for the attribute flow you want to configure.

When choosing "Advanced" and press "New" - this will pop-up a new window where you can choose "Rules extension" and set a Flow rule name for this specific mapping (there will be a name generated based on your attribute flow).

When pressing "OK" - this will unlock the "Management Agent Rules Extension" picker in the last step ("Configure Extensions") of the setup of the Management Agent.

Here you can create your own Management Agent Rules Extension based on the logic you explained in your question.

If you need help to create a Management Agent Rules Extension you can follow this link which will show how a generic extension would look like: [Creating an MA Extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/connector_space/2016/08/19/creating-an-ma-extension/)